# Spaces of matrices and projective spaces

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Consider $\mathbb{C}^8$ i.e. 8 copies of the  field of the complex numbers. I want to identify it with the set of matrices 2x4 $(z_{00},z_{01},z_{02},z_{03},z_{10},z_{11},z_{12},z_{13})$ now i have to consider the subset $X$ of $\mathbb{P}^7$ of matrices of rank 1. My question is: can I consider $X$ as the segre embedding of $\mathbb{P}^3 \times \mathbb{P}^3$ in 
$\mathbb{P}^7$? Since the condition to define $X$ is that 2x2 minors are zero i.e.
$z_{0i}z_{1j}-z_{0j}z_{1i}=0$ and it seems the definition of the Segre variety.
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Your question is this? Is $ \Bbb P ^3 \times \Bbb P ^3$ a subset of $\Bbb P^7$, if so is it a segre embedding of the former in the later?

Comment: The vanishing of $2\times 2$ minors give you a codimension 3 subvariety, so it can not be six dimensional. I will let you check what exactly it is.

Comment: @Mohan sorry but it's not really clear to me, why it has codimension 3?

Comment: It is a theorem of Eagon-Northcott. If you take an $r\times s$ matrix of variables (so $rs$ of them) the vanishing of $k\times k$ minors defines a variety of codimension $(r-k+1)(s-k+1)$. In your case, $r=2, s=4, k=2$.

Comment: @Mohan ok so it is not a trivial problem